# Django Serialize to Json from Super class

Tags: json, django, serialization

I'm trying to figure out if there is any efficient way to serialize a queryset from superclass. My models:

```
class CampaignContact(models.Model):
    campaign    = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, related_name="campaign_contacts", null=False)
    schedule_day    = models.DateField(null=True)
    schedule_time   = models.TimeField(null=True)
    completed   = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)

class CampaignContactCompany(CampaignContact):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company_contacts', null=False)

class CampaignContactLead(CampaignContact):
    lead    = models.ForeignKey(Lead, related_name='lead_contacts' ,null=False)
```

I want to create a json with all campaign contacts may it be leads' or companys'

Answer (score 1):

Django has a built in serializer documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/) but it might not work as well considering how you structured your models:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", CampaignContactCompany.objects.all())
```

I imagine you could run that on both tables and combine the two sets but it would introduce a bit of overhead. You could also create a static `to_json` method in CampaignContact which takes two query sets from the other two tables and formats/combines them into json.

Maybe you have reason to model your tables as you did but based on observation it looks like you will have 3 tables, one never used and two with only a company and lead field different which is probably not ideal. Typically when relating a record to multiple objects you would simply put the lead and company field on the CampaignContact table and let them be null. To get only company contacts you could query `company_contacts = CampaignContact.objects.filter(company__isnull=False).all()`